# How to get String from a NSTaggedPointerString?

Tags: ios, objective-c

[image]

It's about a Get network request, for more information please see this pic.
I want to get the argument "pilotCode", but its value is "0xa00006e....", I want to get its real value which is "admin", please tell me what should I do?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem just now.
just add this code:
 "NSString *realStr = [NSString stringWithString:pilotCode];"